# Парсер steam на java (jsoup)

Tags: jsoup, парсер, java

Пытаюсь запарсить страницу инвентаря стимовского профиля, но как оказалось та часть страницы которая мне нужна - отсутствует в "`view-source`" (гугулхрома) и соответственно `jsoup` тоже не видит ее.

```
Document doc;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197960860649/inventory#570")
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
    .get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    int i = 0;
    for (Element l : links) {
        // получаем значения с href атрибутов
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + l.attr("href"));
        System.out.println("text : " + l.text());
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("\ncount : " +i);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Вся информация находится в блоке `class="trade_item_box selectableNone"`, но если смотреть не через инструменты разработчика (в гуглхром) то информации не видно.

Собственно как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 1):

Смотреть и разбираться, каким образом заполняется этот блок (см. js-скрипты), и как и откуда подтягиваются данные для заполнения (см. ajax запросы).